# Symfony form & entity & choice constraint confusion

Tags: php, forms, symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm

I've got Doctrine entity with some choice field, let's say that it looks like this:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="color", type="string", nullable=false)
 * @Assert\Choice(choices = {"red", "green", "blue"}, message="Choose valid color")
 */
 protected $color;
```

And now I've got a form that's associated with my entity, let's say that specific field looks like that inside of it:

```
$builder->add(
    'color',
    'choice',
    array(
        'choices'  => array(
            'red'   => 'Red like roses',
            'green' => 'Green like grass',
            'blue'  => 'Blue like sky'
        ),
        'expanded' => true
    )
);
```

As far as I'm now, it's quite clear that possible values are duplicated inside constraint and inside the form. But let's go further, I'd like to display my entity inside of a template, so I must do something like that:

```
{% if entity.color == 'red' %}
Red like roses
{% elseif entity.color == 'green' %}
Green like grass
{% elseif entity.color == 'blue' %}
Blue like sky
{% endif %}
```

So we've now got a third place where not only values, but also labels are duplicated. I've thought of something like a service that serves as a twig extension and can be injected into the form builder but it doesn't solve duplication with constraint. Now I've got no idea  how to solve it, I'd really like to have just one single place where I define things like that and most of all I'd like to keep them inside of entity as annotations but I don't know how to proceed with this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding the choices in your mapping, you should [provide them with a callable](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/constraints/Choice.html#supplying-the-choices-with-a-callback-function). You could use [my enum package](https://github.com/greg0ire/enum) for that.

Comment: That looks like something worth to check out, thanks very much! But I'm not sure if I like using static methods inside of a project based on a full dependency injection armed framework. Isn't there any similar DI solution for that?

Comment: Well, if you look at the first link, you'll see that it is an article from the symfony docs, so if they recommend static methods, I think you can safely use that. Enums are classes that answer very fast and have no dependencies, so there would be little to no benefit to mock them. Plus, static methods are not really incompatible with DI : you can still inject the class name if you want to.

Comment: But it's not only testing case - they provide much less flexibility. If you'd like to provide intl or use those enums inside of templates it could possibly become more incompatible with general DI architecture. Most of web applications are built upon the data so if you've got even very little inconsistencies with architecture of the application in model layer, it can very likely escalate on higher levels. Unfortunately that inconsistency is coded into the framework so I don't think that I can do much with this for now. Thanks again for your answer, I think I'll stick to your solution!

Comment: Yeah, it's not only testing, but as I said, static methods are not incompatible with DI, since you can inject the name of the class with the static methods. They're just less convenient because you can't use type hinting to make sure the class implements a given interface. Please note that if you really don't like that, [your callback does not have to be static](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3648#issuecomment-4936689)

Comment: Sorry for another comment, the one before was too long anyways and this one regards something else. I think that I've found a DI solution based on yours, in previous deleted comment I've asked you if you want PR but now I see that it will make your library dependent on twig and Symfony DI container. Anyway I'll publish my work on github so we can talk about it later. Btw: regarding non-static call with choice - as far as I see it can call non-static method only if it's method of the same entity.

Comment: Ok, looking forward to seeing that ;)